# Console version of Nuget erroring out on Package.config file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am getting the following output when trying to run nuget on my packages.config file:

```
Feeds used:

  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
`
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.RC.2.53.0.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.Support.2.53.0.
Restoring NuGet package NUnitTestAdapter.2.0.0.
Restoring NuGet package NUnit.2.6.4.
Restoring NuGet package System.Threading.dll.1.0.2856.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.WebDriver.2.53.0.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.2.53.0.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->    System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

This is run on a Windows Server 2012 box, with jenkins on it.

I've tried registering the dll as is mentioned here:

https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/Known-Issues

This command:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLangproj.olb"
```

The above command did not fail when I ran it, but it also did not fix the issue.

Here is my packages.config file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnitTestAdapter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.RC" version="2.53.0" targetFramework="net452" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="2.53.0" targetFramework="net452" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="2.53.0" targetFramework="net452" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium" version="2.53.0" targetFramework="net452" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Threading.dll" version="1.0.2856.0" targetFramework="net35-client" />
</packages>`
```

Its important to note that this is being run on a Windows Jenkins Slave. I did install Visual Studio on it but for now its being run as a licensed trial. I really DONT want to have it with a license if possible. Also, I am running nuget from the command line (in a Jenkins template). For now I have it pointing directly to the nuget site to get its packages but eventually it will be on a corporate nexus.

Here is the error as it is reported in Jenkins:

```
 Call to NuGet
 Unknown option: '-encodedCommand'
 Finished calling Nuget
```

I believe the encodedCommand statement is a powershell thing.

Here is a detailed output from running from powershell in detailed Verbosity:

```
C:\bin\nuget.exe install F:\Jenkins\workspace\<some company>\
<username>\e2CsharpSeleniumGit\ParallelSelenium\packages.config -Verbosity detailed
Feeds used:
  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

Restoring NuGet package Selenium.RC.2.53.0.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.Support.2.53.0.
Restoring NuGet package NUnitTestAdapter.2.0.0.
Restoring NuGet package NUnit.2.6.4.
Restoring NuGet package System.Threading.dll.1.0.2856.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.WebDriver.2.53.0.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.2.53.0.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct f
ormat.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ConsoleProjectContext.Log(MessageLevel level, String message, Object[] args)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageRestoreManager.<RestorePackageAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageRestoreManager.<PackageRestoreRunnerAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageRestoreManager.<RestoreMissingPackagesAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.ConsoleProjectContext.Log(MessageLevel level, String message, Object[] args)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageRestoreManager.<RestorePackageAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageRestoreManager.<PackageRestoreRunnerAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageRestoreManager.<RestoreMissingPackagesAsync>d__35.MoveNext()<---
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: According to the error message, please check the your input content first, make sure the input content is correct. And I have tested your packages.config file in my Visual Studio, which can restore the packages successful. So I suggest you restore packages through powsershell without Jenkins to confirm whether this issue related to powsershell or Jenkins.

Comment: I did try in powershell and it fails there as well.

Comment: I would try adding the argument `-verbosity detailed` when you run nuget restore. That should cause the exception callstack to be output which may provide a better idea where NuGet is failing.

Comment: Matt I have updated the post above with the verbose output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may come from Nuget not being able to access the repository. This happened to me because I did not have my proxy settings set using the nuget config settings via the command line:
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/Command-Line-Reference#config-command

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolved your issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try restore your packages with powershell on Windows Server 2012 with following steps, which I have run successful based on your packages.config file in my side.

First, create a scrip file (.ps1) which used to find the packages.config file in your solution root and then read them to run the nuget restore command to restore the packages.

```
#This will be the root folder of all your solutions - we will search all children of this folder
$SOLUTIONROOT = "C:\Projects\"
#This is where your NuGet.exe is located
$NUGETLOCATION = "C:\Projects\NuGet\NuGet.exe"

Function RestoreAllPackages ($BaseDirectory)
    {
        Write-Host "Starting Package Restore - This may take a few minutes ..."
        $PACKAGECONFIGS = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $BaseDirectory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
            Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -eq "packages.config")}
        ForEach($PACKAGECONFIG in $PACKAGECONFIGS)
            {
                Write-Host $PACKAGECONFIG.FullName
                $NugetRestore = $NUGETLOCATION + " install " + " '" + $PACKAGECONFIG.FullName + "' -OutputDirectory '" + $PACKAGECONFIG.Directory.parent.FullName + "\packages'"
                Write-Host $NugetRestore
                Invoke-Expression $NugetRestore
            }
    }

RestoreAllPackages $SOLUTIONROOT
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Second, right-click this file to choose **Run with Powershell** to execute the script. Then it will start to install the packages based on the found packages.config file.

Comment: $BaseDirectory is undefined. Did you really mean to use $SOLUTIONROOT there?

Comment: I'm using $BaseDirectory as parameter in RestoreAllPackages function and it works fine in my side.

Comment: Ah got it!! Thanks! The problem ended being the proxy server. It's fixed now!